# Link of iframe open in the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm a newbie here and I want to open a link from clicking a button on iframe to be opened in the parent page. here's the code that I use and currently it opens the link in a new window.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="http://www.khadimtours.com/images/kaba-box1.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <label class="sansserif"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userid" required>

        <label class="sansserif"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pswrd" required>
        <button type="button" onclick="check(this.form)">Login</button>    

      </div>

      <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" class="cancelbtn" onclick="reset(this.form)">Cancel</button>    
      </div>    
    </form>

    <script language="javascript">
        function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/ {
         /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
         if (form.userid.value == "user1" && form.pswrd.value == "user1") {
            window.open('http://user1') /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
         } else if (form.userid.value == "user2" && form.pswrd.value == "user2") {
            window.open('http://user2') /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
         } else {
            alert("Invalid Password or Username") /*displays error message*/
          }
    }
        function reset(form) {
            document.getElementById().reset();
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Note: I'm designing a website on wix and using wix html/iframe to create login form

thanks

Comment: parent.open .... etc?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML structure, to help us understand what is supposed to open where.

Comment: I tried to change it from window.open to parent.open, but it's still not working

Comment: Hi Aydin, I've provided the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Add the optional second parameter as '_parent' in window.open(URL, '_parent');
Please check with the real URL.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your reply. But it doesn't work. I put the second parameter and the button didn't do anything when I clicked it.

Comment: Hi Jay, yes I changed the URL to the real one but it's still not working. BTW, I'm designing a website on wix and using wix html/iframe to create login form